# How to Run Google Shopping Api on db update externally?

Tags: magento, google-shopping-api

I am using Google Shopping Api in Magento 1.7.

> But i am also running an external script to update product price
>   directly in database.

So i need to run Google Shopping API after the script has completed the updation.
Can any please help me regarding this?

Comment: So, what did you try?

Comment: I am new to magento ,so have no idea how to procedd or what to try